# Playing coop games on Duels of the Planeswalkers

Tags: steam, mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers

Is it possible to play the Two Headed Giant or Coop Campaign modes in Duels of the Planeswalkers, the Magic the Gathering game, on a PC?

When I attempt to load these it tells me I need to attach a game pad and reload the game, which seems pretty stupid and potentially impossible in the PC version of the game.  Is there any way to work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up finding http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1580040 and using PPJoy to emulate a joystick using my keyboard and got it working.