# Does XBox gamepad emulator software exist for the PC?

Tags: emulation, controllers

What I'm hoping to do is use a second keyboard and/or mouse in the place of a gamepad for games that require a gamepad to enable multiplayer gaming.  I've noticed a few games that are XBox ports have this requirement so was hoping someone could point me to some software.

Comment: All I've managed to find is a project which makes non-Xbox gamepads usable in an Xbox gamepad's stead. I don't think that really helps you, though.

Comment: No, I stumbled across that same one too and had a look at it.  Clever set-up, but not what I was looking for.

Comment: I've got to ask... What god forsaken games require a gamepad on the pc version to play multiplayer?! That's just wrong on so many levels...

Comment: Magic the Gathering: Duels of the Planeswalkers.  Got it cheap off Steam because I'm a recovered MtG addict but you miss out on about half the game in single player only, and to play multiplayer it lets you control Player 1 with the keyboard/mouse, but Player 2 "has" to have a controller of some form.

Comment: Hey, can you guys post the link to the software you mentioned? The one about non-Xbox gamepads act like Xbox gamepads? Such link might help people who accidentally find this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[X360CE](https://www.x360ce.com/) is a good choice.

This is based on the [ViGEm](https://vigem.org/) virtual controller driver.

Answer (score 1):

[PPJoy](http://ppjoy.blogspot.com/) can be a solution - it can make a virtual joystick from any other input device. 
However, that virtual joystick has an unsigned driver, so it won't work properly under Vista/Win7.

Comment: PPJoy was what I ended up using (see http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10590/playing-coop-games-on-duels-of-the-planeswalkers/11143#11143), but it doesn't quite fit with my original question.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge such software does not exist. Most of the hacking work in the area is in making gamepads do keyboard like things, rather than emulating gamepads with keyboards.